# Проблема со входом на свой сервер TCP Python

Tags: python, сервер, tcp-ip, сетевое-программирование, socketserver

Вкратце: написал вот такой вот небольшой сервер на Python, но при подключении к нему с виртуалки и вводе username происходит такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу разобраться, в чём проблема.

```
class RequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.request.sendall("Auth panel\nEnter the username: ".encode())
        username = self.request.recv(1024)
        if username.strip() != "tzk":
            self.request.sendall("[-] Username is invalid!\nExit\n".encode())
            return -1
        
        self.request.sendall("Enter the password: ".encode())
        password = self.request.recv(1024).strip()

        if md5(password.encode()).hexdigest() != passwordhash:
            self.request.sendall ("[-] Password is invalid\nExit\n".encode())
            return -2
        
        self.request.sendall("Hello, admin!\n".encode())

class ThreadedTCPServer (socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len (sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv [1])
    else: 
        print ("Usage Python " + sys.argv [0]+ "<port>")
        sys.exit(-1)
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", port
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST,PORT), RequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    server_thread = threading.Thread( target= server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = False
    server_thread.start()

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            break

    server.shutdown()
    server.server_close()
```

Comment: Сейчас поменял неравенство на равенство, логин пропускает в любом случае ( даже при вводе tzk), а вот с паролем всё нормально, предположу, что по какой-то причине не правильно считывается строка с логином при подключении.

Answer (score 0):

по сети передается ещё и нажатие enter. надо почистить строку.

```
if username.strip() != "tzk":
```

п.с. вычитывание tcp по .recv(1024) не является надежным. для хорошей программы вам нужно разработать протокол

Comment: Поменял строку по ваше ответу, но ничего не вышло, всё та же проблема.